# Horizontal navigation bar in extjs4 app

Tags: web-applications, extjs, yii

I want to add horizontal navigation bar to my app that developed by extjs4.1, I add toolbar to viewport for this purpose.

```
var toolbar = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
    id: 'header',
    region: 'north',
    items: [
        {
            // xtype: 'button', // default for Toolbars
            text: 'Button'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'splitbutton',
            text : 'Split Button'
        },
        // begin using the right-justified button container
        '->', // same as { xtype: 'tbfill' }
        {
            xtype    : 'textfield',
            name     : 'field1',
            emptyText: 'enter search term'
        },
        // add a vertical separator bar between toolbar items
        '-', // same as {xtype: 'tbseparator'} to create Ext.toolbar.Separator
        'text 1', // same as {xtype: 'tbtext', text: 'text1'} to create Ext.toolbar.TextItem
        { xtype: 'tbspacer' },// same as ' ' to create Ext.toolbar.Spacer
        'text 2',
        { xtype: 'tbspacer', width: 50 }, // add a 50px space
        'text 3'
    ]
});
var viewport = Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
    layout: {
        type: 'border',
        padding: 5
    },
    defaults: {
        split: true
    },
    items: [toolbar,{
```

but i want to create horizontal navigation bar via server because any type of users has specific nav bar for example admin can see createUser in his nav bar but other users can't see it in nav bar.I don't know how can i do this with toolbar in extjs4. Is there any alternate way to do it? or how can i create toolbar items via server for any user?

Answer (score 1):

So, for example when you login - you return from server data with user access, that related to your toolbar(or whatever how you get this data).
You have your controller, that manage your view. Your view contains your toolbar. But by default your toolbar is hidden.
You can add to your toolbar methods like - showAdminButtons(), showSimpleUserButtons().
As soon as you get from server data with your user access - you check what is the user and call in your view method that you need.
But my suggestion if your toolbar should changed during user interactions - create all buttons that you need and only show/hide what you need at correct time. This will prevent to create in dom every time buttons. Otherwise if you will create toolbar only once - create this buttons in method showAdminButtons() for example.
And don't forget the rule - not trust data from client. And check is it allows to perform this action or not.